# Can I cap off a gas line and leave it inside a closed joist space?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

I am renovating my kitchen and will be switching from gas stove to induction cooktop. The gas stove is currently hooked up to a 3/4 inch iron pipe coming through the subfloor (below it is a drywalled finished basement). The wall where the old stove is located is coming down, so I cannot have the pipe sticking out.

Can I simply remove the valve, cap it off with a 3/4” iron cap and Rectorseal, and then 1/4 turn the whole assembly at the lower elbow so it is tucked away into the joist space? Or should I remove the pipe down to elbow and cap it with an threaded plug? The subfloor will be patched and then covered with a new hardwood flooring. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Am I to understand that the difference in your two proposed solutions is just where to cap the gas?  One idea is for the cap to go where the valve is now and you'd just tighten (or loosen) the 90 in the picture until the (now) vertical pipe is low enough to cover.  Your second idea to be replacing the 90 with the cap.  Do I have that right?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor That's right. With the first idea, I would tighten to clear the subfloor. But most importantly, if I seal it and tighten it properly, is it okay to have a live line capped off like this inside joists space? I've seen other posts where people said hidden gas lien must be soldered. I just cannot find a good source of how that is done. And frankly, if I can secure it just as well with a compression fitting, I'd rather do that. There is no shut off to this line (besides the meter shut off) as far as I am aware. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a plumber or someone well versed on codes but, intuitively, I'd say to put the cap as close to the source as possible which means to replace the 90 with the cap rather than keeping the 90.  Either way, none of it is going to be accessible after the fact so there seems to be no benefit from keeping the 90.  There may be some safety reason which insists you find where this branch starts from and cap (or do away with the tee) there instead of either of your proposed methods but that'll be for the safety police to bring up. I've never heard of soldering gas lines in any form

Comment: Personally, I'd never attempt to bring a flame close to a gas line unless it was purged before hand and purging your gas line would require injecting some inert gas at the source and that would be rather involved.

Comment: The critical point here is whether a gas line termination must be accessible, I think.

Comment: Basically , if it leaks,you have a problem ; If it does not leak , you do not have a problem , wherever it is.

Comment: I'd really suggest that you talk to your local gas company and/or building inspector to ensure that whatever you do is to code. If there is _any_ problem and it were to leak and cause an explosion that would be bad at least, fatal at worst. The last thing you want is for the insurance company to figure out that you did something not to code and add insult to injury by denying claims.

Comment: I don’t see how a properly installed plug or cap would be any mor a concern that the property installed elbow and stub up you currently have.

Comment: @kris I agree with both Isherwood and freeman. It may not make sense but the same reason electrical junction boxes have to be assessable I would believe the gas fitting would also OR the equivalent electrical code would require abandoned lines to be removed. A small cover behind the stove to allow future use access may be all that is needed. Calling the gas company would not be so difficult...++

Comment: Can’t leave cover S the wall behind is being removed and stove relocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of the solutions you mention will work, but I recommend, if you have enough room, completely removing the elbow and installing a cap on the horizontal line in the floor. This way there are fewer connections, therefore fewer leak points. Of course, make sure you leak test any joints you move or work on.

There is nothing wrong with a gas line terminating in a floor, other than the difficulty of trying to use it for something in the future. But it's no more dangerous than having any other gas joint in the floor.

The *ideal* solution would be to find where that branch line begins, and cap it there. That way you remove all potential leaks after the origin point. However, I'm not sure that would be easy for you, as you stated that the basement is drywall-finished.

For your reference, here's a link to Minnesota's gas code. It says nothing about gas line terminations. It mentions that gas *valves* must be accessible, but that doesn't apply to your situation, as you will be removing the valve.

https://up.codes/viewer/minnesota/mn-fuel-gas-code-2015/chapter/4/gas-piping-installations#4

Comment: Thank you, finally a practical answer. I am aware of how to do it properly, with proper tools, shut it off, seal it, leak test it. Quite honestly, I’d rather do it myself than trust a plumber to do a meticulous job. I’m sure most will but so can I.